# Reliably detect 16 bit process

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring, 16-bit

Due to the need to run a 15+ year old application I wish to create a watchdog program to ensure a 16 bit application is running on a 32 bit version of Windows XP Pro and start it if necessary. Normally I'd use EnumWindows() to look for the application's window. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, or at least not reliably, for 16 bit apps.

Given that I have absolutely no control over the code in the application in question, how can I reliably detect whether or not it's running? I'm coding this in C (not C++ or C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to enumerate processes (e.g., [`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) with [`GetModuleFilenameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). If you don't find an instance of `ntvdm.exe`, then *no* 16-bit process is running, and you can stop there. If you do find an instance of `ntvdm.exe`, you can use [`VDMEnumTaskWOWEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963831%28VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the 16-bit processes running in it.

Back when it was still under the original owners, I posted [an article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/article.php/c1419/) on CodeGuru demonstrating how to do all of this. It'd take a bit of work to make it compile under a modern compiler (e.g., it's old enough that it uses `iostream.h` instead of `iostream`, but the process enumeration part should still be pretty much right (though, looking at things, you'll also need to enable the `SeDebugPrivilege` for it to work on Windows 7).

Comment: I was just going to post that CodeGuru link - beat to it by the original author.

Comment: @Yann -- yup. Looking at it, I might have to post an updated version to the Code Project. It needs updating to work on modern systems and with current compilers...